# Make checkbox checkable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have hidden checkbox and I can't reach JS code which allows me to do checkbox checkable. How can I do it?

I tryied some JS from stackoverflow, but it didn't work.

Here is my code http://fiddle.jshell.net/ta7w7bb8/

CSS:

```
    .obalform label.checkbox{
    font-size:18px;
    color:#2d2f36;
    width:478px;
    margin:auto;
    text-align: left;
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.checkbox::before{
    content:"";
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background:url(http://i.imgbox.com/dMtoesFn.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-top: 14px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}



.checkbox.checked::before{
    content:"";
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background:url(http://i.imgbox.com/fpOcnxmf.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-top: 14px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.checkbox:hover::before{
    content:"";
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background:url(http://i.imgbox.com/fpOcnxmf.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-top: 14px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

input[type=checkbox]{display:none;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="obalform">
          <div class="radek">
              <label class="checkbox" for="check1">souhlas se zasíláním slevových kupónů,akcí a novinek</label><input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="souhlas">
          </div> 
      </div>
```

And I tryied solution from this topic -> [HTML checkbox onclick called in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197702/html-checkbox-onclick-called-in-javascript)

Comment: Always post your code in your question please. Also, you've posted no effort in writing the JavaScript to accomplish what you asked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the CSS3 :checked selector but you MUST change the HTML structure before... I have wrote a sample for you:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Clear/ta7w7bb8/4/ (with this code you don't need to javascript)

---

Know that in my sample I used an iconic font called "Font Awesome". It's better because with this font you shouldn't use images and the page load is lesser

Comment: Thank you very much, finally I choose this, because I know Bootstrap and FontAwesome, it's easier for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to do the same with-out jQuery you could do it like this:

```
function getLabel(needle) {
    var labels = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
    var texts = [] ;
    for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        var label = labels[i];
        if(label.getAttribute("for") == needle) {
            return label;
        } 
    }
    return null;
 }

function checked() {
    var label = getLabel('check1');
    var selection = this.checked ? "checkbox checked": "checkbox";

    if ( selection ) label.setAttribute('class', selection); 
    else label.removeAttribute('class');
}

// add event listener to checkbox
var el = document.getElementById("check1");
el.addEventListener("click", checked, false);
```

It's more code than jQuery but it's lighter and loads faster. It depends on what you're going to do.

You can find the fiddle [here.](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ta7w7bb8/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is artificially inserting an image that represents the checkbox's state. The image looks checked when the "checked" class is applied to the `<label>`. You either need to reorganize your CSS/HTML, or you can write some JavaScript that adds or removes the "checked" class to the `<label>` when the checkbox is updated.

The following is a simple jQuery script that will fix the problem with your "checked" class.

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var checked = $this.is(":checked");
        if (checked)
            $this.closest(".radek").find("label").addClass("checked");
        else 
            $this.closest(".radek").find("label").removeClass("checked");
    });
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ta7w7bb8/2/)

Comment: Thank you for code and your time. On your Fiddle is it fine, but can you tell me, what I'm doing wrong? http://apps.8u.cz/test/

Comment: I updated my answer with an explanation of your problem.

Comment: I should also mention that [your page](http://apps.8u.cz/test/) is not working because the JavaScript is invoked before the element is rendered to the DOM. Wrap the code in a [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler like I have shown in the answer and it will work on your page.