# oncheck listener for checkbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have code like this at the bottom of my form.

```
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="agreed">
  I agree to keep my Username and Password confidential and uphold 
  the integrity of this pharmacy
</p>
<input type="submit" id="submit" disabled class="formbutton button-primary" value="Go">
```

I want this a listener in JavaScript to be able to enable the submit button.
I know it might be wrong or something but my JavaScript looks sort of like this

```
function track() {
    if ( document.getElementById("agreed").checked==true ) {
        document.getElementById("submit").removeAttribute("disabled");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("agreed").checked==false
    }
};
```

Comment: make a js fiddle to show what you are trying to do

Comment: How about just call the script when you check the box? 
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197702/html-checkbox-onclick-called-in-javascript

Comment: The dirty way... `<input type="checkbox" id="agreed" onChange="track()">` and your assignment to false needs one =, not 2... `document.getElementById("agreed").checked=false`

Comment: If it works then it isn't wrong, it only might be hard to maintain if you need to do a lot of checks.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can do this for the input:

```
<input type='checkbox' onchange='handleChange(this);'>Checkbox
```

And this for enabling the button:

```
function handleChange(checkbox) {
    if(checkbox.checked == true){
        document.getElementById("submit").removeAttribute("disabled");
    }else{
        document.getElementById("submit").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
   }
}
```

Comment: hey man, thanks for your answer. This is my first project with coding and all...im trying my hands out on this for a friend. Thanks anyways it did work.

Answer (score 3):

Try Below for your requirement using jQuery.

```js
$('#checky').click(function(){
     
    if($(this).attr('checked') == false){
         $('#postme').attr("disabled","disabled");   
    }
    else {
        $('#postme').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="checky"><a href="#">I agree to keep my Username and Password confidential and uphold 
  the integrity of this pharmacy</a>
<br>
<input type="submit" id="postme" value="submit">
```

Using JavaScript, Please refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021848/enable-disable-submit-button-if-checkbox-is-checked-unchecked)