# html change color button if checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, html

I try to change the color of a button if the two checkboxes are checked. But I can't figure out how to do this. I understand that I need javascript, but have no experience at all with javascript.
I copied some lines from internet but this doesnot change the color of the button. So if the checkboxes are checked there should be another style selected for the button.

this is my code sofar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .button1 {
            background-color: #FF0000;
            border: 4px;
            border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
            border-color: red;
            color: yellow;
            padding: 15px 25px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 16px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .button1:hover {
            background-color: green;
        }

        .button2 {
            background-color: #FF00FF;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkbox_checked {
            if (input.getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox' && input.checked)
                n++;
            checkbox_checked.elements.boxes_checked.value = n;

            if n = 2 button.className = "button2";
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">

    <button class="button1">General</button>

    <!-- Insert a table in a div, so this can be hide -->
    <div id="General">
        <table style="width:50%;margin-left:50px;">
            <colgroup>
                <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
                <col style="background-color:yellow">
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td><label class="container"> <input type="checkbox" name="cb_General_1"> <span class="checkmark"></span> </label> </td>
                <td>Protocol name(s) : </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Protocol name(s)" size="35"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label class="container"> <input type="checkbox" name="cb_General_2"> <span class="checkmark"></span> </label></td>
                <td>Order name(s):</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Order name(s)" size="35"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: functions don't do anything till you call them. You better go through adding event listeners first

Comment: it was answered before on stackoverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31705665/oncheck-listener-for-checkbox-in-javascript#31705898

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach `onchange()` to the check boxes. Then simply check both check boxes to change the class accordingly. Try the following:

```js
function checkbox_checked(){
  var chk = document.querySelectorAll('input[name^=cb_General_]')
  if(chk[0].checked && chk[1].checked)
    button.className = "button2";
  else button.className = "button1";
}
```

```css
.button1 {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    border: 4px;
            border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
            border-color:red;
    color: yellow;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button1:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
.button2 {
    background-color: #FF00FF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

  <body style="background-color:#E3CEF6;" >

    <button id = "button" class="button1" >General</button> 

    <!-- Insert a table in a div, so this can be hide -->
    <div id="General">
      <table style="width:50%;margin-left:50px;" >
        <colgroup>
        <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
        <col style="background-color:yellow">
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
          <td><label class="container"> <input onchange= "checkbox_checked()" type="checkbox" name="cb_General_1"> <span class="checkmark"></span> </label> </td>
          <td>Protocol name(s) : </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="Protocol name(s)" size="35"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label class="container"> <input onchange= "checkbox_checked()" type="checkbox" name="cb_General_2"> <span class="checkmark"></span> </label></td>
          <td>Order name(s):</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="Order name(s)" size="35"></td>    
        </tr> 
      </table>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and the explanation. This is what I tried to do

Comment: @Orca, you are most welcome....if the answer solves your problem then you can accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in......thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the attribute `onchange` for the checkbox inputs, and also there are some errors in your javascript code. You can achieve the result like this:

```css
.button1 {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  border: 4px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  border-color:red;
  color: yellow;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
.button2 {
  background-color: #FF00FF;
}
```

```html
<script>
var n = 0;
function checkbox_checked(e) {
 if(e.checked) {
   n++;
  }
  else {
   n--;
  }
  
  document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].className = (n == 2) ? "button2" : "button1";
}
</script>
<button class="button1" >General</button> 

<!-- Insert a table in a div, so this can be hide -->
<div id="General">
<table style="width:50%;margin-left:50px;" >
 <colgroup>
    <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
    <col style="background-color:yellow">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label class="container">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb_General_1" onchange="checkbox_checked(this)">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>Protocol name(s) : </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Protocol name(s)" size="35"> </td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label class="container">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb_General_2" onchange="checkbox_checked(this)">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>Order name(s):</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Order name(s)" size="35"></td>    
  </tr> 
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and the explanation. This is what I tried to do

Answer (score 0):

You are right that you need `JavaScript` but if you do not call the `function` it will do nothing. However, there is a better way of doing it, called `eventListener`. This always 'listens' to your code and fires up when something `changes`.

**Event Listener Example**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check2">
    <button id="button">Watch me change</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    document.getElementById("check1").addEventListener("change", function(){
        if(document.getElementById("check1").checked && document.getElementById("check2").checked){
            document.getElementById("button").style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Explanation**

In the `HTML body` part there are two `checkboxes` both with a unique `ID` (`check1` and `check2`) and a `button` whose `backgroundColor` will change if the two `checkboxes are checked`. Then an `eventListener` is added to `check1` with the `addEventListener` function. Inside it, it checks that both (`&&`) `checkboxes` are checked with the `checked` attribute. If both are `true`, it changes the `backgroundColor` of the given `button`.

**Reference and further reading**

[Article about the `addEventListener` function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and the step by step explanation. This is what I tried to do. Now i see there are several solutions

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var i = 0;
function checkbox_checked(e) {
 if(e.checked) {
   i++;
    
  }
  else {
   i--;
  }
  
   document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].className = (i == 2) ? "button2" : "button1";
}
```

```css
button {
  border: 4px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  border-color:red;
  color: yellow;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button1{
background-color: #FF0000;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
.button2 {
  background-color: #FF00FF;
}
```

```html
<button class="button-css button1" >General</button> 

<!-- Insert a table in a div, so this can be hide -->
<div id="General">
<table style="width:50%;margin-left:50px;" >
 <colgroup>
    <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
    <col style="background-color:yellow">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label class="container">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb_General_1" onchange="checkbox_checked(this)">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>Protocol name(s) : </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Protocol name(s)" size="35"> </td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label class="container">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb_General_2" onchange="checkbox_checked(this)">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>Order name(s):</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Order name(s)" size="35"></td>    
  </tr> 
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and the explanation. This is what I tried to do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one would help you to have an idea. It's just a simple code with html and javascript.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
    var button = document.getElementById("myButton");
    
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
        button.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else {
       button.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="myCheck" type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me<br>

<button id="myButton" style="background-color: red; color: white">Button</button>
```