# DOM Properties with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

Say I want the user to be able to choose the fontstyle using Javascript and a checkbox list.

So I has this code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Style0" />Bold

<input type="checkbox" id="Style1" />Italic

<input type="checkbox" id="Style2" />Underline<br/>
```

Do I need to make a for loop and if it's check then add that to document.body.style.fontStyle? They are allowed to choose more then one box at a time, and apply those styles.

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to choose the fontstyle and then have it immediately update, or choose the fontstyle and have it update at some other time? If the former, then check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31705665/oncheck-listener-for-checkbox-in-javascript) out.

Comment: It would be updated after they pushed a button

Comment: Yeah, so go ahead and check out that link I commented previously. Essentially, you can have an `oncheck` listener which you can assign a function. What'll happen is when the box is checked, the function will be called. Within said function, you can use JavaScript to change the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is have three separate CSS styles as follows:

```
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.italic {
    font-style: italic;
}

.underline {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

And using JQuery you can listen to the event and apply the relative classes to the element.

For example, if you have the following paragraph element:

```
<p id="paragraph">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

In your javascript you'll have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '#style0, #style1, $style2', function() {
        var paragraph = $('#paragraph');

        if ($('#style0').is(':checked') && !paragraph.hasClass('bold')) {
            paragraph.addClass('bold');
        } else if (!$('#style0').is(':checked') && paragraph.hasClass('bold')) {
            paragraph.removeClass('bold');
        }

        if ($('#style1').is(':checked') && !paragraph.hasClass('italic')) {
            paragraph.addClass('italic');
        } else if (!$('#style1').is(':checked') && paragraph.hasClass('italic')) {
            paragraph.removeClass('italic');
        }

        if ($('#style2').is(':checked') && !paragraph.hasClass('underline')) {
            paragraph.addClass('underline');
        } else if (!$('#style2').is(':checked') && paragraph.hasClass('underline')) {
            paragraph.removeClass('underline');
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:**

For a pure JavaScript solution:

```
document.getElementById('style0').addEventListener('change', function() {
    var paragraph = document.getElementById('paragraph');

    if (this.checked) {
        paragraph.classList.add('bold');
    } else {
        paragraph.classList.remove('bold');
    }
});

document.getElementById('style1').addEventListener('change', function() {
    var paragraph = document.getElementById('paragraph');

    if (this.checked) {
        paragraph.classList.add('italic');
    } else {
        paragraph.classList.remove('italic');
    }
});

document.getElementById('style2').addEventListener('change', function() {
    var paragraph = document.getElementById('paragraph');

    if (this.checked) {
        paragraph.classList.add('underline');
    } else {
        paragraph.classList.remove('underline');
    }
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be JQuery?

Comment: @Jona Yes it will. Are you only looking for pure Javascript solutions?

Comment: Yes, as much as I know it would be so much easier with JQuery, our teach specified we have to use Javascript only. So I had a solution then I was like shoot. Is the only option really to make a for loop or if statement and then add the style that way then?

Comment: So I get I can do a few if statments, but how I add mutliple CSS styles? I know it's just a comma, is there a good way to detect if there are multiple styles and add a comma?

Comment: @Jona I updated my answer to include is non JQuery solution. As it relates to adding multiple CSS styles, could you explain a bit more?