# Checkbox and Text Display

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to display text in a `<p>` when checkbox is checked from input modal.

```js
var mayo1 = document.getElementById('mayo1').checked;

if (mayo1.checked == true){
            document.getElementById('order1mayo').innerHTML = "Mayo";
 }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="mayo1" value="Mayo"> Mayo
<p id="order1mayo"></p>
```

Comment: Replace `mayo1` in your `if` condition with `document.getElementById('mayo1').checked` and see if it make sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [oncheck listener for checkbox in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31705665/oncheck-listener-for-checkbox-in-javascript)

Comment: fixed my issue, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The input field checked property gets true or false. So your mayo1 variablee can be a true or false boolean type. In this case if (mayo1.checked == true) is a mistake.
The correct condition is if(mayo1) { ...}

Comment: It's about refactoring but not a mistake.

Comment: For the event: <input type="checkbox" onchange="Changed(this)" />.    function Changed(cb) { alert(cb.checked); }

Comment: I mean that `if(mayo1.checked) {...}` and `if (mayo1.checked == true)` works exactly the same. 
`if(mayo1) { ...}` is not correct because it will always be `true` if html element exists.

Comment: What is happening when you remove the value="Mayo" attribute from input tag?

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens because your code

```
if (mayo1.checked == true){
            document.getElementById('order1mayo').innerHTML = "Mayo";
 }
```

executes only one time immediately after start. You checkbox is not checked at that moment and thus nothing happens.

You have to watch for the changes using `eventListener` and change the text content depending on current checkbox status. See [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-q9qvpo?file=index.js) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually handle an event and go from there;

```js
isChecked = (i) => {
    const o = document.getElementById("order1mayo");
    i === true ?
      o.innerHTML = "Mayo":
      o.innerHTML = "NO Mayo";
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" 
       id="mayo1" 
       value="Mayo" 
       onchange="isChecked(this.checked)">Mayo
       
<h4 id="order1mayo"></h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `mayo1` var is true or false depend on your checkbox, so `mayo1.checked` is wrong expression...

Try this instead...

```
if (mayo1) {
  document.getElementById('order1mayo').innerHTML = "Mayo";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to see if `mayo1.checked.checked` is true - use only one `checked`:\

```
var mayo1 = document.getElementById("mayo1").checked;
if (mayo1) {
    document.getElementById("order1mayo").innerHTML = "Mayo";
}
```