# check multiple checkbox from first click to second click using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

Sorry for my english.
I have several checkboxes like these:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="1" />1
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="2" />2
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="3" />3
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="4" />4
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="5" />5
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="6" />6
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="7" />7
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="8" />8
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="9" />9
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="10" />10
```

If I check the checkbox number two and the checkbox number seven, it is possible to automatically check with JQUERY the checkboxes from the number two and the number seven?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="1" />1
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="2" checked />2
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="3" checked />3
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="4" checked />4
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="5" checked />5
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="6" checked />6
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="7" checked />7
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="8" />8
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="9" />9
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="10" />10
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is possible, but where is your try ?

Comment: yes possible give a same class name to 2 to 7 digit simple

Comment: there's already an answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197702/html-checkbox-onclick-called-in-javascript

Comment: It is possible with jQuery , but better write a logic rather than same class othervise when you need to modify the code again and again. I think you need to perform the check based on some logic right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I could acheive that:

```js
var checked = [];
$(":checkbox").click(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
       // Optional sanity
       // if you wish to make user available to uncheck 
       return;
    }
    var min = $(':checkbox:checked:first').val();
    var max = $(':checkbox:checked:last').val();
    for (var index = Number(min)+1; index < Number(max); index++) {
      $(`[type="checkbox"][value='${index}']`).prop("checked", true);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="1" />1
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="2" />2
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="3" />3
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="4" />4
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="5" />5
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="6" />6
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="7" />7
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="8" />8
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="9" />9
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="10" />10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pseudo` selectors `first` and `last`and loop between then

```js
$('[type="checkbox"]:checkbox').change(function() {
  var first = $('[type="checkbox"]:checked:first').val();
  var last = $('[type="checkbox"]:checked:last').val();
  for(var i = first; i <= last; i++){
    $('[type="checkbox"][value="'+i+'"]').prop( "checked", true );
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="1" />1
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="2" />2
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="3" />3
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="4" />4
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="5" />5
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="6" />6
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="7" />7
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="8" />8
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="9" />9
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="10" />10
```

Comment: consider chosing checkbox also  in selector $('[value="'+i+'"]').

Comment: unnecessary to select `first` and `last` while looping, better `i = first + 1; i < last`

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly possible. You could do something like this (it'll require you to add an id to your inputs. I'll use `myCheck`):

```
let first = null;

function clicked(event) {
    if(first) {
        let second = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);

        let a = first < second ? first : second;
        let b = first < second ? second : first;

        for(let i = a; i <= b; i++) {
            $('#myCheck[value="' + i + '"]').attr('checked', true);
        }

        first = null;
    }
    else {
        first = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);
    }
}
```

Then, just use `clicked` on your `click` event. Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/7pf45mbz/1/

In some cases, you might have to use `prop` instead of `attr`. However, for your use case it would probably be better user experience if you used a `select` element with `multiple` instead of checkboxes.